# Benefit of getting an instance in Java

Tags: java

I've seen this code which has two different way its written

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester.boot();
    new tester();
```

Tester class:

```
public static tester instance;

public static void boot() {

    if (instance == null)
        instance = new tester();
}

public Tester() {
    System.out.println("test made");
}
```

What is the difference beetween `tester.boot();` and `new tester();`

Are there any benefits to either?

Comment: A method (other than a constructor) or object that is used only to create an instance of an object is called a *factory*.

Comment: You should post short code examples that compile successfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three concepts being displayed here:

- [**Lazy Initialization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)
- **[Static](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-the-static-keyword-in-java.html)**
- **[Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming))** (at least the lack thereof)

Tester class:

```
if (instance == null)
    instance = new tester();
```

That's used when you wish to control the construction of an object.  The variable `instance` controls if `new Tester()` will be called by `boot()`.

This can be used to implement [**Lazy Initialization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).  That's the practice of delaying construction of an object until it is needed.  It's typically used when construction is both expensive and not always needed.  Here it is delayed until `boot()` is called.  Lazy Initialization is not only used for singletons.  [**Some**](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077568/learn-java/java-tip-67--lazy-instantiation.html) believe that using Lazy Initialization in java to create a `singleton` is actually wrong because of how the class loader works.  They claim it's a habit ported over from c++ where it made sense.  As a pattern, singleton has been controversial enough that **[some call it an anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292109/why-implementing-a-singleton-pattern-in-java-code-is-sometimes-considered-an-a)**.

Tester class:

```
public static tester instance;
```

`boot()`, constructs a `Tester` object, sets `instance` to that object (Note: `tester` should have been capitalized).  The fact that `instance`, which is of type `Tester,  resides in the`Tester`class means that`Tester`is [**self referential**][7], like the nodes in a linked list.  But, unlike nodes, because`instance`is`static`, all`Tester`objects have the same copy of`instance`.

Because boot never puts what it constructs anywhere but in `instance`, only one `boot()` constructed `Tester` object ever exists at any one time, so long as `instance` is never copied anywhere.  It easily could be, because it's `public`.

So long as `instance` is never set back to `null` `boot()` will construct a `Tester` only once no matter how many times it's called.  Since `instance` is `public` it could be set to `null` at any time by anything that knows about `Tester`.  Doing so would allow `boot()` to construct again and the old `Tester` object would be forgotten (garbage collected).

Since `Tester`s constructors have not been made `private` there is no guaranty that `Tester` is never constructed by something other than `boot()`.  That means there could still be many `Tester` objects running around.  But they all have one `instance` in them that may or may not be themselves.

A classic singleton would have Lazy Initialization, be self referential, and be encapsulated in such a way that at most only one `Tester` object would ever exist.  However, There is nothing here that proves this was meant to be a singleton in the first place.  This could be a construction optimization gone horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of implementation of a SINGLETON pattern, in Java.
Look here to understand the concepts behind this pattern [click here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Shortly, you want to use this pattern if you want to have an instance of the class **Instance** trough all application's life cycle.

To understand it, the key in your code is in the part **"if(instance == null)"** *{instance should be written with lower key, as it should be a class variable}.*

If you go simply with the "new ..." any nuber of instances of this variables could be created.
If instead you use the *boot* method, you are sure that the instance is always the same.

Anyway in the implementation you have written something is missing.

You should refer to this [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html), where there is also a complete implementation in Java programming language.

Answer (score 0):

`boot` is useless, you're not showing how `Instance` is used. But I think it's there to implement a [singleton](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=singleton%20java), meaning to assure that only one instance of the class is created. I don't think it's a good implementation as `Instance` can be used by mistake without being initialized.

When you write `new tester()` then you're creating a *new* instance of `tester` object.

Please follow [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your variables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific--if you use tester.boot() it would set "instance" properly, if you call the constructor directly, it will not.

This is a really broken version of the singleton pattern, to do it correctly the constructor should be made private which makes new Tester() impossible.

Also, the boot method should look a little more like:

```
public synchronized static Tester  boot()
{
    if(instance == null) {
        instance=new Tester();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

and even that is probably iffy.

Answer (score 0):

read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320101/are-there-any-advantages-of-making-the-method-makeevent-static/27320291#27320291) comment to know when it makes sense to have an instance and when not.